# How to select two column values in my linq to sql query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm beginner in `linq to sql` this:

```
var query = (from p in behzad.STATUS
                         select p);

            var taskCounts = (from worker in query.ToList()
                              group worker by worker.date into g
                              select g.Select(x=>x.natije) 
                                ).ToArray();
```

but in in this line `select g.Select(x=>x.natije)` select just `x.natije` ,i want select another filed `x.qaza`,how can i write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an anonymous type:-

```
 var taskCounts = (from worker in query
                   group worker by worker.date into g
                   select g.Select(x=> new { natije = x.natije, qaza = x.qaza } );
```

Since this returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T,T>>` you will have to use two `foreach` loops to get the data:-

```
foreach (var item in taskCounts)
{
    foreach (var x in item)
    {
         tempo = x.natije  //here
    }
}
```

Also, you can find the first `natije` from first group but it may result in error:-

```
 string tempo = res.First().First().natije;
```

Comment: thanks ,can you give me any solution to get taskCounts[0].Natije value from that query?

Comment: which my query must be update?please write complete to me,i'm beginner.

Comment: excuse me,but i  want write this ,string tempo=taskCounts[0].natije; but i get error.

Comment: @user3671271 - Hey sorry got u wrong, you will have to use two foreach loop to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can creat a dynamic object on the select:

```
       var query = (from p in behzad.STATUS
                     select p);

        var taskCounts = (from worker in query.ToList()
                          group worker by worker.date into g
                          select g.Select(x=> new  {  Natije = x.natije,  Qaza = x.qaza }) 
                            ).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks ,can you give me any solution to get taskCounts[0].Natije value from that query?